# change a value automatically in a specified date and time in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, date, triggers

I want to set the value of a field of a table in sql to TRUE at a specified date and time, in asp.net.
how can I do this?
Is there any way to do this in sql with triggers?

Comment: is it one time requirement or you want to apply this often?

Comment: It will be required more than one time but not offtenly

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using MS SQL Server, [Triggers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) are generally used to do an action based on a `Insert, Update, Delete` command.

If the asp.net code you have is running then at the set time you could get it to send an update statement to the database.

If that's all the asp.net program is doing then maybe look at schedulling a [SQL Job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135739%28sql.105%29.aspx)